# Unable to Capture Frame using EMGU CV windows 10 64 bit

Tags: emgucv

[image]

I am not understanding why this error is coming when I am trying to Capture Image using VideoCapture Class in EMGU CV 3.3

Comment: Are you using a nuget package?

Comment: Yes, it is solved now, it is because I have used an older code with the newer library